# react can not show console log variable

Tags: reactjs, console

why my log not showing anything ? is ths because the variable isLoading state ?

my code :

```
 function getColumns(data) {
  const columns = [];
  const sample = data[0];

  console.log("theSample" + sample);
```

[image]

and i call it from here :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isLoading: true };

    if (this.state.isLoading === false) {
      //const data = getData();  
      const data = this.state.dataExt;     
     // console.log(data);

      const columns = getColumns(data);
      this.state = {
        data,
        columns,
        visible: false
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes because you are setting `this.state = { isLoading: true };` and then checking `this.state.isLoading === false`.  That's why it is not  calling the function `getColumns`. Condition never executes true part here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you only call `getColumns` when `this.state.isLoading === false`, and the initial value of your `isLoading` state is true. Therefore, unless you update your `isLoading` state, `getColumns` wouldn't be called and your log wouldn't show up.